# Dealing with Projectile Misses and trajectory

Tags: c#, xna

I have several formulas I use for firing a bullet at a target, but it all breaks down when the player moves from his original position and the bullet reaches the old position of the player as intended.

When PlayerPosition == BulletPosition, how do I make the bullet keep going in the right direction if it misses? My problem is once the bullet reaches where it was supposed to go it stops and I need a new formula to keep it moving.

If it hits the player, that's easy, remove the item, but I can't seem to find a good solution. Below is some code, it's super simple for now.

```
 var movement = PlayerPosition - Position;
        if (movement != Vector2.Zero)
            movement.Normalize();
        //var angle = Math.Atan2(movement.Y, movement.X);
        Position += movement*_projectileMoveSpeed;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you intend the bullet's speed to be affected by the distance from the player?

I'd just save the velocity, then use that in the future frames. In pseudocode:

```
to shoot a bullet:
    direction is sign(PlayerPosition - Position)
in each frame:
    for each bullet:
        modify position by direction * projectileMoveSpeed
        handle collision (player or screen edge)
```

Comment: I think the issue is that PlayerPosition is never incremented in my instance. I think the fix is to add PlayerPosition += My new Vector at the end, so it can never reach the final location and will die at the edge.